# Copy from different workbook based on 3 criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy data from the workbook `15B2[...]" (sheet DATA)` to the worbook. I'm starting the macro from `(sheet getDATA)`. The macro should copy the cells in column `F`, `H` and `DA` if the cells in column `N` , `CI` are blank and the column `DA` has the value *3-Incompletion* in it.

Somehow the macro stops after the second if statement and goes straight to `End if` without copying anything:

```
If InStr(.Range("DA" & LastRow7).Value2, "3-Incompletion") > 0 
And Trim(.Range("N" & LastRow7).Value2) = "" 
And Trim(.Range("CI" & LastRow7).Value2) = "" Then
```

I don't know exactly what this function does. Does it look in every row and counts the rows that matches the criteria?

Here is the complete code:

```
Sub insertINCOMPLETION()

Dim dataWB As Workbook
Dim reportWB As Workbook
Dim workB As Workbook
Dim incomplRNG As Range
Dim LastRow6 As Long
Dim LastRow7 As Long

For Each workB In Application.Workbooks
    If Left(workB.Name, 4) = "15B2" Then
        Set dataWB = workB
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If Not dataWB Is Nothing Then
    Set reportWB = ThisWorkbook

    With reportWB.Sheets("getDATA")
        LastRow6 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    End With

    With dataWB.Sheets("Data")
        LastRow7 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

        If InStr(.Range("DA" & LastRow7).Value2, "3-Incompletion") > 0 
        And Trim(.Range("N" & LastRow7).Value2) = "" 
        And Trim(.Range("CI" & LastRow7).Value2) = "" Then
            Set incomplRNG = Application.Union(.Range("F8:F" & _ 
            LastRow7),.Range("H8:H" & LastRow7), .Range("DA8:DA" & LastRow7))
            incomplRNG.Copy
            reportWB.Sheets("getDATA").Range("B" & LastRow6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

I need help to solve this problem because I'm not really good at programming VBA.

Comment: what do you mean by `macro stop`, is it an error (which one) or Excel crashes, or what?

Comment: The macro goes straight to "End if" and skips the copy part. The Excel file the macro is looking for is open and the sheet "getDATA" exists.

Comment: Criteria in `If statement` are not matched. Moreover, you are checking only the last row of data and trying to copy all if the last row matches criteria. is it what you need?

Comment: Moreover, you wrote `I don't know exactly what this function does.`... `If...Then`, `Trim` and `Instr` functions and statements are those of basics of  VBA. If you don't understand them put in some effort to google for definition and usage, please :)

Comment: And learn to indent your code properly as can see easily the If to which the End If relates. Presumably `dataWB` is Nothing?!

Comment: The macro should look in every cell in the columns and copy the row-range of them is the criteria matches. I already googled it, but I wasn't sure because someone suggested me to use these statements. I thought there was something like a second meaning.

Comment: @Kazimierz Jawor how can the `dataWB` be nothing if it's open. I use this code quite often and every time it worked. But you could be right but I don't know how to fix this because I have a open file that starts with "15B2".

Comment: are you sure it is `15B2` and not `15b2` while `If statement` is case sensitive in VBA.

Comment: @Kazimierz Jawor Yes it's a capital letter. In the workbook I have a similiar starting macro that works. I also added a "fake-line" in the workbook I want to get the data from. Even if I put the matching criteria in the last line, the macro won't copy the range. Also, how can I change the macro that not only looks into the last column. It should look in every row and check if the criteria matches.

Comment: I don't think your `dataWB` is nothing as you would get error earlier in the code. Try to run your macro with F8 and check how it is going. Hover mouse over you variables to check if `lastRow6` and `lastRow7` having expected values.

Comment: It's showing me that lastrow = 0. But I checked in another macro that works and it displays the same, maybe it's a bug? Also changing the row to F8 [...]  and change the data doesn't work either. The macro still doesn't copy anything. Is there a better solution for this? I think I need to change the code no matter if we can find a solution because it only checks for one row. Is there a solution to look for specific criterias and then copy the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As near as I can make out your intentions from your question, your code and above comments the procedure below should do what you want. It isn't tested but any errors it might contain should be minor ones you can fix easily (or point them out to me here).

The first procedure copies blocks of data after examining the last row of the same. Version_2 examines each row and copies only those which meet the criteria.

```
Option Explicit

Sub insertINCOMPLETION()

    Dim DataWb As Workbook
    Dim ReportWB As Workbook
    Dim LastReportRow As Long
    Dim LastDataRow As Long

    For Each DataWb In Application.Workbooks
        If InStr(1, DataWb.Name, "15B2", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then Exit For
    Next

    If Not DataWb Is Nothing Then
        Set ReportWB = ThisWorkbook
        With ReportWB.Sheets("getDATA")
            LastReportRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End With

        With DataWb.Sheets("Data")
            LastDataRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

            If (InStr(1, .Range("DA" & LastDataRow).Value2, "3-Incompletion", vbTextCompare) > 0) And _
                    (Trim(.Range("N" & LastDataRow).Value2) = "") And _
                    (Trim(.Range("CI" & LastDataRow).Value2) = "") Then
                .Range("F8:F" & LastDataRow).Copy ReportWB.Sheets("getDATA").Range("B" & LastReportRow)
                .Range("H8:H" & LastDataRow).Copy ReportWB.Sheets("getDATA").Range("C" & LastReportRow)
                .Range("DA8:DA" & LastDataRow).Copy ReportWB.Sheets("getDATA").Range("D" & LastReportRow)
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Sub insertINCOMPLETION_Version_2()

    Dim DataWb As Workbook
    Dim ReportWB As Workbook
    Dim LastReportRow As Long
    Dim LastDataRow As Long
    Dim R As Long

    For Each DataWb In Application.Workbooks
        If InStr(1, DataWb.Name, "15B2", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then Exit For
    Next

    If Not DataWb Is Nothing Then
        Set ReportWB = ThisWorkbook
        With ReportWB.Sheets("getDATA")
            LastReportRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End With

        With DataWb.Sheets("Data")
            LastDataRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            For R = 8 To LastDataRow
                If (InStr(1, .Cells(R, "DA").Value2, "3-Incompletion", vbTextCompare) > 0) And _
                        (Trim(.Cells(R, "N").Value2) = "") And _
                        (Trim(.Cells(R, "CI").Value2) = "") Then
                    ReportWB.Sheets("getDATA").Cells(LastReportRow, "B").Value = .Cells(R, "F").Value
                    ReportWB.Sheets("getDATA").Cells(LastReportRow, "C").Value = .Cells(R, "H").Value
                    ReportWB.Sheets("getDATA").Cells(LastReportRow, "D").Value = .Cells(R, "DA").Value
                    LastReportRow = LastReportRow + 1
                End If
            Next R
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! Now I can see some data getting copied. Somehow it doesn't filter for "3-incompletion" and just copies everything. I think it doesn't check if the cells are blank also.

Comment: Also it seems like `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` doesn't work here.

Comment: This has to do with that you have entrusted faulty code with the task of conveying what you want done. Try plain English.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Sorry for my bad English. Unfortunately, it's really important that all 3 criteria match. Otherwise I could simply delete the blank cells. But how is it possible that the code looks for "3-incompletion" but copies everything.

Comment: It's possible because you told us to look for "3-incompletion" and the blank cells only in the last row. Now I added a variation above which checks each row starting from row 8 - just guessing lol: